# How to destroy an Hashmap C

Tags: c, function, hashmap, free

I created an Hashmap in which I have a lot of keys. My trouble is : how can I destroy my hashmap?
If I write  `free`  in my hashmap , it will become NULL or something else?
I thought that was enough `free` function, but when I try to call my function:

```
int isEmpty(struct hashmap *t){  
    if(t!=NULL) {
        int sizeT = t->size;
        for (int j = 0; j < sizeT; j++) {
            if (t->list[j] != NULL)
                return FALSE;    // FALSE, if it is full
        }
        return TRUE;   // TRUE, if it is empty
    }else{ 
        printf("Empty!");
        return 2;
    }
}
```

Before this function I run  `free` so in  `isEmpty` it may enter in  `else`  statement instead it enter in  `if` where the condition is (t!=NULL). How can I definitely destroy it?

Comment: Is this a hash table you wrote yourself or a third-party library?

Comment: Why is a function called `isEmpty` expecting a structure you haven't shown us intended to "destroy" a hash map? How does the structure look like? What do you expect `free` to do?

Comment: You talk about `free()` like you expect it to modify a variable? Doesn't work that way.

Comment: I created my own hash table @Shawn
with `isEmpty` function I expect , after a `free`, that it enters in the `else ` statement cause I deleted my hash table. I call `free` in order to deallocate all nodes and delete hashmap structures. @j3141592653589793238

Comment: Your else block will only be entered if you call the function with a null pointer...

Comment: The hash table after a ` free` returns NULL or not? @Shawn

Comment: `free()` doesn't return anything.

Comment: The hash table after `free` will be worth NULL or not? @Shawn

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand what you're trying to ask. Maybe someone else can.

Comment: @cocoricò After a `free`, the hash table doesn't exist anymore. So there isn't something that can return a `NULL`. Only something that exists can return something, and if you do have something that does still exist, why should it return `NULL`?

Comment: After you call `free`, do you try to use a (now invalid) pointer to something you freed for any purpose? After you call `free`, any pointers you had to the freed block are invalid and you shouldn't use their values for anything.

Answer (score 0):

assuming that you allocated the hashmap using `malloc()` or `realloc()`

`free()` won't necessarily assign NULL to `t`, so you should make the assignment yourself after `free()`

Comment: Only very rarely does it make sense to assign `NULL` to `t` after doing `free(t);`. The vast majority of the time, you just don't use `t`'s value anymore. In many cases, it's about to go out of scope anyway, so such an assignment is pointless.